# Latest record for each user number?

Tags: sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I did search, but the uniqueness of each question makes it hard for me to "translate" it for my dataset.

I have table A named: CLOGS17
With a sub-set of the data and fields shown:

```
SERIALNO    EVDATE                     SYSNO    AREA    USRNO
4           2017-01-01 02:03:48.000    1        4       10
4           2017-01-01 02:09:00.000    1        4       10
4           2017-01-01 02:24:44.997    1        6       10
4           2017-01-01 02:56:50.000    1        2       18
5           2017-08-08 02:03:48.000    1        4       10
5           2017-01-09 02:09:00.000    1        4       10
6           2017-04-03 02:24:44.997    1        6       10
8           2017-05-05 02:56:50.000    1        2       18
```

My goal is to retrieve all records where the combination of SERIALNO + SYSNO + AREA + USRNO has not been used in the last 30 days (inactive user essentiallY) so I can delete that USRNO.

Desired output from above data would be (newest record for each SERIALNO, SYSNO, AREA, and USRNO distinct combination):

```
SERIALNO    EVDATE                     SYSNO    AREA    USRNO
4           2017-01-01 02:09:00.000    1        4       10
4           2017-01-01 02:24:44.997    1        6       10
4           2017-01-01 02:56:50.000    1        2       18
5           2017-08-08 02:03:48.000    1        4       10
6           2017-04-03 02:24:44.997    1        6       10
8           2017-05-05 02:56:50.000    1        2       18
```

I am then able to get only those within the last 30 days.

Given the table data below ("Table B"), it is a list of all stored users:

```
SERIALNO    CONTID  SYSNO   AREA    USRID
36          001     1       *       1
36          001     1       *       18
36          001     1       *       2
36          001     1       *       29
36          001     1       *       36
36          001     1       1       10
```

This table contains ALL users in the system.

How can I return all the users from Table B that have not been used for a given CONTID, SYSNO, and AREA?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question it would be as simples as a `group by` of a select on the desired fields:

```
SELECT SERIALNO,
       SYSNO,
       AREA,
       USRNO,
       MAX(EVDATE)
  FROM CLOGS17
 GROUP BY SERIALNO,
          SYSNO,
          AREA,
          USRNO
```

Since you didn't provide enough information about the second part. This query will give you the output you show in your question.

So, to get all users that doesn't meet your 30 days criteria (whatever it are), you just do a `left join` of you user table with the above query seeking the nulls for the query above, like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tableb tb LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT SERIALNO,
            SYSNO,
            AREA,
            USRNO,
            MAX(EVDATE)
       FROM CLOGS17
      GROUP BY SERIALNO,
               SYSNO,
               AREA,
               USRNO) a
          ON tb.SERIALNO = a.SERIALNO, 
             AND tb.SYSNO = a.SYSNO
             AND tb.USRNO = a.USRNO 
  WHERE a.AREA is null
```

Comment: Thanks Jorge. I've added some more info to OP. So your query helps a bit - it returns all the combinations that HAVE been used in the past 30 days (after I added the 30 day filter code). How can I now get all the ones that have NOT been used using the now-provided table data that stores all user combinations?

Comment: Edited it, see if it meets your needs. Oh, it is late here at my end (almost 4am) , I'm going to sleep now. If there is something wrong I will see it later.